# Interface Bullet Physics library to MATLAB

Tags: matlab, collision-detection, bulletphysics, bullet

I'm trying to use the Bullet Physics library within MATLAB. I need to do Collision detection and therefore I wanna use the GJK algorithm. In MATLAB it is possible to compile a so-called MEX function. With the MEX function it is possible to call your own C or C++ programs from the MATLAB command line as if they were built-in functions.
My problem is that the Bullet library is very big with a lot of files, header function and so on and I am not really familiar with programming. I looked for simpler implementations and found:

https://github.com/ElsevierSoftwareX/SOFTX_2018_38

It is GJK wrote in C code with a file that gains the wanted MEX function. This file looks like this:

```
% CLEAR ALL VARIABLES
clearvars

% SELECT OPTIMISATION FLAG - FASTER BUT NOT SUITABLE FOR DEBUGGING
if 0
    optflug = '-g'; %#ok<*UNRCH>
else
    optflug = '-O';
end
% SELECT SILET COMPILATION MODE.
if 1 
    silflag = '-silent'; 
else
    silflag = '-v';
end

% TRY COMPILING MEX FILE
fprintf('Compiling mex function... ')
try
mex('../lib/src/openGJK.c',...  % Source of openGJK 
    '-largeArrayDims', ...      % Support large arrays
    optflug, ...                % Compiler flag for debug/optimisation
    '-I../lib/include',...      % Folder to header files
    '-outdir', pwd,...          % Ouput directory for writing mex function
    '-output', 'openGJK',...    % Name of ouput mex file
    '-DMATLABDOESMEXSTUFF',...  % Define variable for mex function in source files
    silflag )                   % Silent/verbose flag

    % File compiled without errors. Return path and name of mex file
    fprintf('completed!\n')
    fprintf('The following mex file has been generated:')
    fprintf('\t%s\n',[pwd,filesep,'openGJK.',mexext]) 
catch
    % Build failed, refer to documentation
    fprintf('\n\n ERROR DETECTED! Mex file cannot be compiled.\n')
    fprintf('\tFor more information, see ')
    fprintf('<a href="http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html">this documentation page</a>.\n\n')
    return
end
```

So I tried to do a similar thing with the Bullet library, but I even don't know which source file to use. I tried the 'btBulletCollisionAll.cpp' in the 'src' folder. But like I'm said I'm not really familiar with C++ and I'm wondering why there are only a lot oof header files. Also I need to tell MATLAB where the header files are and how to link them.

So basically I just want to call a function on MATLAB like this:

```
dist = GJK(shapeA,shapeB);
```

Here is the Bullet depository:
https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3

Thanks a lot for your help

Addit: I don't use the SOFTX_2018_38 because I also need EPA algorithm and I think the Bullet library is efficient and robust implementation.

Comment: You can not simply compile the library, some adjustement have to be done. Everything is explained in the [documentation](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/standalone-example.html)

Comment: Hey obchardon, I know that I can't compile the whole library at once. But it would be helpful to know which source file I have to compile and which header files I need to link for that to get a function like this: `[dist,simplex] = GJK(shapeA, shapeB)` and `penetrationDepth = EPA(shapeA, shapeB, simplex)`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know a .mex defines a single MATLAB function. The library you pointed seems to be a python library, so I would suggest you to review  [quickstart guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10sXEhzFRSnvFcl3XxNGhnD4N2SedqwdAvK3dsihxVUA/edit#heading=h.2ye70wns7io3) (88 pages), use it in python and then you think about porting to MATLAB.

It seems you can [run python libraries directly in MATLAB](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-python-libraries.html)

About python, it is a so well covered subject that will not try to write anything else here, there are tons of tutorials you can find with a quick search.

Comment: Hi @Bob, thanks for your quick respond. I wondered that the original "bulletphysics.org" website passes you tp "pybullet.org". So I am a little confused because the doc as well as the quick start guide tells me that it is written in C++. Also GitHub shows that about 80 percent of the code is in C++

Comment: It is written in C++ but for a python interface. You could translate all the interface, but it is not a good idea to do that before you understand very well the API. If you understand the API I think you will be happy to do your application in python. And even if you want MATLAB then you can create a custom interface from the python layer instead of the C++ layer. Disclaimer: I don't know the library, I am only giving general advices.

Comment: ah ok. I tried to install pybullet but it didn't worked for me. It seems like that I need "pip" and I get an error. I am really a big amateur in those things and don't know what to do. I have to work with MATLAB (working on my bachelor thesis, so I have to use MATLAB). I don't even know if it is possible to connect Python with MATLAB. But I know that I can use the function that are implemented with C++ because I saw papers where they use them. Nevertheless thank you for your help.

Comment: If you insist you can [Create a C Source MEX file](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/standalone-example.html). You should not be required to use any specific tool in the university, it is meant to open possibilities not closing. But as I said you will only create a function with a MEX file. Best luck with it.